# how to upload and display ppt in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a whiteboard based on the html5 canvas and have added various functions like undo, redo, pencil, upload image, upload pdf and so on. Could anyone help me with the upload ppt functionality. Basically what I need is to be able to upload and display the ppt on the canvas.

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: Since this is my very first time using javascript i was following different websites for each of the functions. For this particular function i was unable to find any instructions and hence have not tried anything yet.

Comment: You could somehow convert it to HTML and then put it on the canvas.

Comment: I am thinking of somehow converting the slides to images and uploading it to the canvas using drawImage() function of the canvas

Comment: That could be possible. You might want to look into HTML2Canvas - https://html2canvas.hertzen.com

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the slides to images and then display them using the HTML canvas `drawImage()`.

```js
function drawOnCanvas() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('imgCanvas').getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('img'), 0, 0);
}

window.onload = drawOnCanvas
```

```html
Image:
<br>
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/FFFFFF/?text=HTML%20Canvas' id='img'>
<br>
<br>
Canvas:
<br>
<canvas id='imgCanvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: Would you have any idea on how to convert ppt slides to images using javascript.

Comment: @JoshuaJinu You could send the file to the server and convert it there using [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ppt-png)